# How do I keep morekeywords from being highlighted in a comment?

Tags: listings, highlighting, lstlisting, lstdefinestyle

Say I have the following listing style:

```
\lstdefinestyle{custCpp}{
  language=c++,
  keywordstyle={\bfseries}, % keyword color
  keywordstyle = [2]{\color{blue}\bfseries},
  otherkeywords = {QuadraticException},
  morekeywords = [2]{QuadraticException},
  commentstyle=\color{gray},
  upquote=true,
  showstringspaces=false  
}
```

How do I keep `QuadraticException` from being bolded in comments?

See the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{custCpp}{
  language=c++,
  keywordstyle={\bfseries}, % keyword color
  keywordstyle = [2]{\color{blue}\bfseries},
  otherkeywords = {QuadraticException},
  morekeywords = [2]{QuadraticException},
  commentstyle=\color{gray},
  upquote=true,
  showstringspaces=false  
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style = custCpp]
// Not styled: try catch else if then
// Styled: QuadraticException

int x = 2;

for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
    if (i > 0) {
      throw QuadraticException("test working exception class");
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for the help!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simply to remove the line

```
otherkeywords = {QuadraticException},
```

from your style definition. `otherkeywords` is used to define keywords that include characters which `listings` classifies as *other* characters (usually most symbols), hence the name. Parsing of these keywords works differently and is a bit buggy at the moment. The correct option to use is `morekeywords`.

Without that line your code is correctly output as

[image]